# Android studioでdrawableに9-patchのpngファイルの置き方を教えてください。

Tags: android-studio

基本的な質問ですいません。
Android studioのdrawableフォルダに9-patchファイルを置きたいのですが、
Drag & Dropでは置けないので置き方がわかりません。
教えていただけないでしょうか？

Android studio: 1.1.0

～追記～
以下はGoogleのsampleですが、新しいプロジェクトを立ち上げて、以下のようにdrawableフォルダの下にtile.9.pngを置きたいのですが、置き方が分からないので教えてほしいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コピー＆ペーストでいけると思います。
ファイルをコピーした後、drawableフォルダをアクティブにし、
ペーストするとコピー先のファイル名と追加先のフォルダを確認するダイアログが表示されます。

[image: コピーダイアログ]

Comment: 回答が遅れて申し訳ございません。ちゃんとできました。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルが表示されているビューの左上に`Android`と表示されているので、そこをクリックして`Project`にすると、Eclipseの時と同様のファイルツリーになります。

[image: Project Viewへの切り換え]